# How to update a specific column in Firebase with Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, firebase

I am using Kreait\Firebase. I hope you are familiar with it. This is my code

```
public function firebase() {
  $serviceAccount = ServiceAccount::fromJsonFile(__DIR__.'/private-again.json'); 

  $firebase = (new Factory)
  ->withServiceAccount($serviceAccount)
  ->withDatabaseUri('https://private.firebaseio.com/')
  ->create();

  $update   = ['id'  => 1];

  $database = $firebase->getDatabase();

  $reference = $database->getReference('user/details')
  ->orderByChild('id')
  ->equalTo('2')
  ->update($update);

  print_r('Good');die;
}
```

So, What I am trying to do here is, I want to update the id which is equal to 2 to 1. But it throws an error like this Call to undefined method Kreait\Firebase\Database\Query::update(). And, I do not know if I am doing it okay or not.

**P.S.:** I was able to get the snapshot so that part went good with equal to 2.